# I want to capture the text occurring between the two regex matches

Tags: python, regex

For example, this is my string (it is a text from html)

```
html_text = """
TABLE OF CONTENTS

PART I  
| ITEM 1. BUSINESS  
| ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS  
| ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED CONFLICTS  
| ITEM 2. PROPERTIES  
| ITEM 3. LEGAL PROCEEDINGS  

    We believe that relations with our employees are good; however, the competition
    for such personnel is intense, and the loss of key personnel could have a
    material adverse impact on our results of operations and financial condition.

    ITEM  1A. |  RISK FACTORS  

    Set forth below and elsewhere in this report and in other documents we file
    with the SEC are descriptions of the risks and uncertainties that could cause
    our actual results to differ materially from the results contemplated by the
    forward-looking statements contained in this report.

    ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED CONFLICTS

    Our future revenue, gross margins, operating results and net income are
    difficult to predict and may materially"""
```

I have written a regex to capture "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS" (*not from Table of Contents*)

```
re.search(r"(ITEM.*1A)*.+(RISK FACTORS).*\n+(?!\w)(?!.*ITEM.*1B)", html_text)
```

and another regex to capture "ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED CONFLICTS" (*not from Table of Contents*)

```
re.search(still trying to figure this out)
```

I want to capture all the text that occurs between these two matches.
The final text string should look like:

```
final_text = """    ITEM  1A. |  RISK FACTORS  

    Set forth below and elsewhere in this report and in other documents we file
    with the SEC are descriptions of the risks and uncertainties that could cause
    our actual results to differ materially from the results contemplated by the
    forward-looking statements contained in this report."""
```

Comment: re.search(r'(.*ITEM\s*1A\.\s\|(.|\n)*)(ITEM 1B.)',html_text)[1]

Comment: @RishabGupta Did that work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I wanted only the text of "Item 1A. Risk Factors". Also, I have 1000s of such files with different formats. Therefore, my regex should work on all formats. I used a part of your regex to write a new regex. However, it is still breaking at some points, I am unable to figure out how to fix that.
((ITEM.*1A)(.|\n){0,30}(RISK.*FACTORS)(?!\.|\"|,)(_|\*|\s|\W)*\n+(.|\n)*)(?:ITEM.*1B)

Comment: @RishabGupta Can you show what you have and what it should match? Should the pattern be more generic instead of matching `ITEM`? Or can you share a regex101 link with the texts that should match?

Comment: All my files contain "Item 1A. Risk Factors" and "Item 1B". However, it also has a Table of Contents, so I have to make sure that it does not capture from TOC and should rather start capturing where the section begins. Here is the example of one of the files. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_SX8HXVDXD1tnFFp9XH54XHaeWFiISlo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Thefourthbird the link in the previous comment is where my regex works.

this is the link where my regex is breaking.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mIysbv4B3xln3Igjqbanc2vJJ3YyMIeH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RishabGupta Can you try it like this? `_(item[ \t]+l?\d+\.[ \t]+[^_*\r\n]*)` The values are in the first capturing group.

Comment: You might use a positive lookahead to get the match only but that will be more inefficient `(?<=_)item[ \t]+l?\d+\.[ \t]+[^_*\r\n]*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195301/discussion-between-rishab-gupta-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for You:

```
re.compile(r"^(    ITEM  1A. \|  RISK FACTORS.+\n(?:\n.+)+)", re.MULTILINE)
```

Can be seen here at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/h8brwJ/1) however note that it works different over there due to not using `re.compile(REGEXP, REGEXPOPTION)` settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match from `ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS` and all that follows and then match the next `ITEM 1B. UNRESOLVED CONFLICTS` and all that follows in a separate match you could use a repeating pattern with a negative lookahead and match all following lines that do not start with `ITEM`,  spaces , digits and an uppercase char.

```
^[ \t]+ITEM[ \t]+\d+[A-Z]\.[ \t]+.*(?:\r?\n(?!.*\bITEM[ \t]+\d+[A-Z]).*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^`
- `[ \t]+ITEM` Match 1+ spaces or tabs followed by `ITEM`
- `[ \t]+\d+[A-Z]\.` Match 1+ spaces or tabs followed by 1+ digits and uppercase char
- `[ \t]+.*` Match 1+ spaces or tabs followed by any char except a newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Math a newline
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `.*\bITEM[ \t]+\d+[A-Z]` Match `ITEM followed by tab or spaces, 1+ digits and an uppercase char
  - `)` Close negative lookahead
  - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/awlQVV/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7N1S7q)

For example:

```
regex = r"^[ \t]*ITEM[ \t]*\d+[A-Z]\.[ \t]+.*(?:\r?\n(?!.*ITEM \d+[A-Z]).*)*"
print(re.findall(regex, html_text, re.MULTILINE))
```

Note: if you only use spaces, this part `[ \t]+` can be shortened to a single space followed by an plus sign `+`

```
^ +ITEM +\d+[A-Z]\. +.*(?:\r?\n(?!.*\bITEM +\d+[A-Z]).*)*
```